# Find with Sum and Group By

Tags: cakephp

My MODELS ARE

- 1 Project hasMany Records
- Records belogsTo Project

Table project (id, pname)
Table records(id, projects, tempo)

I want to get a SUM of time spent per project.

In My RecordsController i do:

```
$total = $this->Record->Project->find('list', array('fields' =>
    array('SUM(Record.tempo) as tempoGasto','Project.pname'),
       'group'=>array('Project.pname')
));
```

But this gives me this error:

> missing entry for table "Record"`

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: How do your Model files look for `Record` and `Project`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = $this->Registo->Project->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array(
      'SUM(Registo.tempo) as tempoGasto',
      'Project.pname'
   ),
   'group'=>array('Project.pname'),
   'joins' => array(
      array(
        'alias' => 'Registo',
        'table' => 'records',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
          '....'
        )
    )
));
```

I can't figure out your foreign key so, fill it up. This should work fine